# HTML encode not working properly for URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kentico, html-encode

I am trying to generated a URL:

> Get-it-Together-Stavros-Zenonos-amp;-Katerina-Ko?viewmode=0

Where you can see "amp;"  after that url is not generating

Like below:

> Get-it-Together-Stavros-Zenonos-amp

See my code below which is generating URL

```
<a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<%=HTMLEncode(CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentContext.CurrentDocument.AbsoluteURL)%>" onClick="return popup(this, 'notes')">  
 <img src="<%# Eval("twittericon") %>" alt="twitter icon" />
</a>
```

Could you help what i need to do to generate full URL?

Comment: You don't want to HTMLEncode, but URLEncode instead. Check if whatever server side language you're using has a function to do that. Otherwise you'll have to use `replace()` manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Comment: URLEncode not worked , still its cutting at those ; . AbsoluteURL give the URL with ; but while i share it in twitter it just give till ; not the rest of it

Comment: hey its worked with URLencode , i did a mistake of putting in wrong place

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you put this as answer i will aceept it

Comment: @SmartestVEGA added it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `HTMLEncode` on the value in the URL. Instead you should use `URLEncode`.